# Combining Multiple Tags into a single tag with a regex

Tags: php, html, regex

I know I shouldn't be parsing HTML with a regex but I don't have control of the source HTML.

I have a single line html consisting of a lot of `<i>` tags which represent pixels.

```
<i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i class=cfefefe></i>
```

My problem is finding counting and replacing the  tags

How can I construct a regex to find and count tags without classes `<i></i>`

Ideally I'd like an array to show the count of connecting empty `<i>` tags:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5      //<i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i>
    [1] => 3      //<i></i><i></i><i></i>
    [2] => 8720   //etc etc
    [3] => 14
    [4] => 320
)
```

Comment: What is your current regex?

Comment: If it's just a fixed string you're looking for, you don't need a regex. Or do you also need to consider other cases?

Comment: I was stumped after I got to here: (<i></i>+?)

Comment: Essentially I'll be building a list of the counters then replacing each string of tags with a single tag spanning that number of pixels. `<i class="s320"></i>` class `.s320` will have a width of 320 pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var your_line = "<i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i class=cfefefe></i>";

var result_set = your_line.match(/<i><\/i>/g);
```

Example:

```
> your_line.match(/<i><\/i>/g)
["<i></i>", "<i></i>", "<i></i>", "<i></i>", "<i></i>"]
```

To match consequent `<i></i>` together:

```
> your_line.match(/(<i><\/i>)+/g)
["<i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i><i></i>"]
```

Comment: Many thanks, I used `substr_count($matched, '/')` to count the occurrences.